# Jenkins maven test(selenium tests) command giving errors

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have created a maven project for selenium and it is executing fine when I run the command "mvn test" in command prompt.

I pushed it to a repository in GitHub and created a Jenkins job (Using Git plugin and Maven Integration Plugin).

When I run that job it is pulling the source code from GitHub to Jenkins Workspace but the job is failing. The following is the console output.

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\workspace\Automation Scripts After Build Job
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\workspace\Automation Scripts After Build Job\.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/subbustech/seleniumtraining # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/subbustech/seleniumtraining
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.38.1.windows.1'
 > git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/subbustech/seleniumtraining +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 589e4dc1d99da6a581431416bff866524e5cbab8 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 589e4dc1d99da6a581431416bff866524e5cbab8 # timeout=10
Commit message: "pushing new changes"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 54429
[Automation Scripts After Build Job] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5/bin/java" -cp C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-agent-1.14.jar;C:\maven\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main C:\maven C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3044.vb_940a_a_e4f72e.jar C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-interceptor-1.14.jar C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.14.jar 54429
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\workspace\Automation Scripts After Build Job\pom.xml test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< SeleniumTraining:SeleniumTraining >------------------
[INFO] Building SeleniumTraining 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SeleniumTraining ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\workspace\Automation Scripts After Build Job\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ SeleniumTraining ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 122 source files to C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\workspace\Automation Scripts After Build Job\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.010 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-10T23:30:54+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project SeleniumTraining: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x412a7bf9) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x412a7bf9 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\HP\.jenkins\workspace\Automation Scripts After Build Job\pom.xml to SeleniumTraining/SeleniumTraining/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SeleniumTraining-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

But if I go to Jenkins workspace and open a command prompt and run the mvn test command it is working fine and running with out any issues.

The following is the pom.xml, I am using.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SeleniumTraining</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumTraining</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
          <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng01.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone help me with what's wrong here?

thank you.

Comment: That seemed to be the issue: `class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x412a7bf9) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x412a7bf9 -> [Help 1]`. You seemed to be using Lombok somewhere... which is the wrong version or using the wrong JDK version etc. ???

Comment: HI @khmarbaise
I am not using lombok anywhere. Moreover if I run the command mvn test in command prompt in Jenkins workspace, it is working fine. But it is failing only when we run it through jenkins job.

Comment: The output says something different. Maybe you are using it indirectly as a transitive dependency... You should check your project..Also you should prevent directories with spaces in there... and fix all the warnings in the build...

Comment: If that's the case then it should fail when I run using cmd in jenkins workspace also. But it is working fine there.